# How does machine learning relate to artificial intelligence?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

For example, is it a subset?

Are they two separate fields in Computer Science?

I have hear conflicting information: one professor said they are synonyms. However, in the courses taught at Stanford CS they are two distinct classes:

CS221 (Artificial Intelligence)

and

[CS229 (Machine Learning)](http://explorecourses.stanford.edu/search?view=catalog&filter-coursestatus-Active=on&page=0&catalog=&academicYear=&q=CS%20229&collapse=)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence#Classifiers_and_statistical_learning_methods, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning

Comment: @D.W ,The OP should do further reading; computational intelligence,artificial intelligence and machine learning.or else we shall get vague answers here.

Comment: @quintumnia I agree with you, but at the same time, if answered well, this could be a good resource for other people in the future.

Answer (score 6):

[Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) is a subset of (the scientific field of) [Artificial Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence).

### What is ML?

Machine Learning is defined by Tom Mitchel:

> A computer program is said to learn from experience E with respect to some class of tasks T and performance measure P if its performance at tasks in T, as measured by P, improves with experience E.

Hence: When you write an algorithm that gets better the more data you give it, then you can call it ML.

### What is AI but not ML?

- [SLAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_localization_and_mapping)
- [Path finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding): [Bellman–Ford algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), [A* search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)
- [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain)
- [cellular automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton)
- Logic: Although a lot of people (e.g. Pedro Domingos) include logic approaches (e.g. with inverse deduction) in Machine Learning, I would rather say it is AI.

  - Fuzzy logic (see [Fuzzy logic vs AI vs Machine learning vs Deep learning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43178123/562769))
  - Knowledge representation / Formal systems

### See also

- [Difference between machine learning and artificial intelligence](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/36341/8820)

Comment: The last paragraph is out of fit! We have to get it right here...those are computational intelligence applications  but not artificial lntelligence

Comment: @quintumnia Translated, the first sentence in the German Wikipedia about [Computational Intelligence](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_Intelligence) says "Computational Intelligence is a subfield of artificial intelligence" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Is it a subset?**

Yes, it's a subset of artificial intelligence and artificial intelligence is a subset of computer science.
AI is a simulation of human intelligence that is coupled with processes, i.e.,

*self learning*  (neither program nor an agent has the capabilities of acquiring of information and rules for using the information).

*reasoning*  (neither program nor an agent uses the rules to reach approximate conclusions or definite conclusion  and self correction.
Are they two separate fields in Computer Science?

**I have heard conflicting information. One professor said they are the synonyms.**

Today machine learning and artificial intelligence are becoming  buzz words all over the media, various applications have been developed, but out of 100%, you find that only 40% is a real application that's considered AI, then the 60% are computational intelligence  applications.

*Hint*: artificial intelligence is the mother of machine learning; algorithms which corrects their mistakes and makes decisions without human help.