# Is Artificial intelligence simply taking decisions on the basis of values produced by a machine learning model

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am researching on AI and its working. Whenever I try to search for AI algorithms, ML algorithms come up. Then, I read the differences between ML & AI. One of the key points mentioned was "AI is decision making" & "Machine learning is generating values and learn new things".

I come up with a conclusion that ML allows us to take generate some sort of values and using AI we can make decisions with those values.

But I am confused with "The weather forecast" problem. Our machine learning model will directly generate the decision that will it rain or not? **Is our ML model lies in the AI domain or I am wrong? Help me!**

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/86816/755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artificial Intelligence is a very broad area of Computer Science which is intertwined with many other fields, and someone might argue that its definition is *the discipline that develops rationally acting systems*.

When it comes to Machine Learning, the generally accepted definition is programming computers to perform a specific task *without specific instructions* about the problem.

Being that broad of a field, AI comprises Machine Learning problems, but the difference between the two areas relies on **how** you devise your system:

- if you make use of problem-specific knowledge in your algorithm: you're outside the ML field;
- if you formulate your problem in a general-enough manner and use a generic algorithm: most likely you're inside the ML field.

I'm sure you have already seen this image from [Nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/deep-learning) a million times already, but it's intuitive to understand what's the relationship between AI and ML: the latter is part of the former.

[image: Nvidia explanations of relationships among AI, ML and DL]

Comment: What is the difference between `problem specific knowledge` & `problem formulation`

Comment: The focus is mostly about the algorithm: in case the solving algorithm makes use of problem-specific knowledge (i.e. rules of chess) and it is tailored on it in order to provide the solution, that is AI; on the other hand, if you're able to encode such knowledge in a way the solving algorithm is actually generic (i.e. least squares minimization) and knows nothing about the domain, that is ML.